# kivy - self not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I am trying to run this Python program from a Python book that I've picked up named "Python The Complete Manual", however the instructions read for Python 2.7 and I am running Python 3.5.

This program runs in the `kivy` environment, as I am using it to create an app. The issue that I'm currently having is that when I run the program, I get an error message that says `'self' is not defined`. I've already tried changing the syntax, moving the functions(because I thought that it would have to read the functions in a specified order), and even removed the whole line completely. I still get the same `self` not defined error no matter how I try.

Here is the code along with the error message:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import kivy
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import ListProperty


class GridEntry(Button):
    coords = ListProperty([0, 0])


class TicTacToeApp(App):
    pass

    def build(self):
        return TicTacToeGrid()


class TicTacToeGrid(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TicTacToeGrid, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def button_pressed(self, instance):
        print('{} button clicked!'.format(instance.coords))


    for row in range(3):
        for column in range(3):
            grid_entry = GridEntry(coords=(row, column))
            grid_entry.bind(on_release=self.button_pressed)
            self.add_widget(grid_entry)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TicTacToeApp().run()
```

Output:

```
    (kivy_venv) root@c0mputer:/home/chavez/Documents/Python# ./ticTacToe.py 
    [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /root/.kivy/logs/kivy_20-01-06_1.txt
    [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1
    [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/home/chavez/Documents/Python/kivy_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kivy/__init__.py"
    [INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.5.2 (default, Oct  8 2019, 13:06:37) 
    [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
    [INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "/home/chavez/Documents/Python/kivy_venv/bin/python"
    [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge log fired. Analysing...
    [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge finished!
    [INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
    [INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_gif (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
    [INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2(['window_egl_rpi'] ignored)
    [INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
    [INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <sdl2>
    [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'3.0 Mesa 18.0.5'>
    [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Intel Open Source Technology Center'>
    [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 520 (Skylake GT2) '>
    [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 3, 0
    [INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'1.30'>
    [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
    [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
    [INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
    [INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
    [INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
     Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "./ticTacToe.py", line 23, in <module>
         class TicTacToeGrid(GridLayout):
       File "./ticTacToe.py", line 35, in TicTacToeGrid
         grid_entry.bind(on_release=self.button_pressed)
     NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

Comment: Your `for row in range(3):` isn't in a class method. It is at the class level, as such there is no such thing as `self`. Either put it in a method and then you can use `self` or put it in a `@classmethod` and use `cls`. You could probably just put it in your constructor, the `__init__`.

Comment: I think for loop will be inside button_presses function

Comment: Looks like an indentation error from here. Your for loop needs to be indented one more level.

Comment: @davidc There is no way to force users to point out the reason for their vote since the vote is secret so it can only be deduced that those who gave you a downvote did not like your question for any reason.

Comment: Not my down vote, but often people downvote questions like this just because it is something you should be able to fix by following a python tutorial all the way through. Though personally I believe this is an *okay* question since this type of bug may be hard to spot for someone unfamiliar with the language or unfamiliar with programming.

Comment: @eyllanesc Thank you for your speedy response. I don't want to force anyone to do anything they don't want to but I was just curious so that I could correct myself and highlight my answer for the next person that needs it.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse I followed the tutorial to a T, however the book that I am using doesn't even post the code in a format that is readable for a beginner in Python. I sort of regret buying it as a Christmas present to myself. :(

Comment: @davidc yeah I've had bad books like that. Though if you want a really really good advanced python book look into Fluent python. That being said welcome to SO. I think you will learn the ropes quickly :).

Comment: @davidc The books intended for kivy will not focus on the basic concepts of OOP as it assumes that the reader has that knowledge as it is a requirement to use kivy since I use it intensively.

Comment: @eyllanesc Good point. Thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

I am new to this forum(only having viewed questions and answers and not actually signing up to the site). Thank you @Error -Syntactical Remorse, that was the correct answer I was looking for. Be it simple but I am fairly new to Python and haven't even heard of `kivy` until I started reading this book. Also, another thing that I do not like about getting the right answer is that the person that posts the question and gets the right answer almost never posts his/her/their code the way it was answered correctly. I just usually see, "Oh! that solved it!"... so, I will post where the correction is here:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import kivy
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import ListProperty


class GridEntry(Button):
    coords = ListProperty([0, 0])


class TicTacToeApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return TicTacToeGrid()


class TicTacToeGrid(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TicTacToeGrid, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for row in range(3):
            for column in range(3):
                grid_entry = GridEntry(coords=(row, column))
                grid_entry.bind(on_release=self.button_pressed)
                self.add_widget(grid_entry)

    def button_pressed(self, instance):
        print('{} button clicked!'.format(instance.coords))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TicTacToeApp().run()
```

Comment: Couple things. 1) Instead of using 4 spaces to indent code use three backticks: ``` (should be under the `esc` key), it will make your life a lot easier. 2) You have an un-neeeded `pass` within `class TicTacToeApp`.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse Thanks, you rock!